# Login com Spring security com md5 + salt

Tags: java, jsf

Login com Spring security
O seguinte problema tenho que pegar os dados de login de um banco de dados ja pronto com a seguinte criptografia md5 + salt
(52212dd409480f88e95611a58257506d:SgkronFw2YWXaUSahmnBP1swqhctw21p) e tenho que comparar esses dados com o do que o usuário vai passar pelo login, mas nao da certo, estava tentando compara so uma parte da senha mais na dar.
aguem ja fez algo semelhante:

http://pastebin.com/PP0t1bBr  //usuarios.java
http://pastebin.com/C20MCWCR  //AppUserDetailsService.java

Comment: a pergunta ainda é a mesma depois de dois anos? :o

Comment: ja resolvi kkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/tgyxEJeh //applicationContext.xml
http://pastebin.com/yhqmpQdN //UsuarioSistema.java

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/dAWn9e7e              //LoginBean.java
http://pastebin.com/tgyxEJeh                 //applicationContext.xml